# How to create snapshot functionality using git submodules?

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

I am working in a project, where the [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) tool is no longer used in the project, thus the current snapshot functionality is now meaningless. However, the same functionality can be achieved using *git submodules*.

I want to come up with a script which basically does this. I have not worked with git submodules. I would appreciate if someone could help me with the workflow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean with snapshots? Submodules already refer to a specific commit of the references repository, in essence what a snapshot is. And each update of that submodule is committed in the main repo, snapshotting the snapshotted state of its submodules.

Comment: By snapshot I mean creating a restore point. With a tool like `repo` one can do a `repo sync` to restore.